# Adding in-line documentation to GoCD

Tags: go-cd

Is there any way to document your pipelines and stages from within GoCD, so that you can add meta-information for people who are not familiar with what they do?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any standard way to do it from within GoCD, but I can think of adding an echo statement as the first task in a job might help achieve to what you're looking for.

Also, If you're using YAML files to describe the pipelines, then you can have the documentation as comments in there.